# SonarQube: Magic numbers should not be used (squid:S109)

Tags: java, sonarqube, magic-numbers

By definition,

> "Magic number" is a value that should be given a symbolic name, but
>   was instead slipped into the code as a literal, usually in more than
>   one place.

This is a perfect example of a magic number

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){       // Noncompliant, 4 is a magic number
        ...
```

and should be changed to something meaningful like

```
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CYCLES ; i++){
        ...
```

But Sonar throws errors for indexNumbers too. 
For instance, I have a DAO class where insert statement has almost 50+ columns and sonar throws error for

```
ps.setString(1 ,...)
```

I am sure this is more readable than

```
ps.setString(INDEX_ONE ,...)
```

Is there anything wrong in my understanding? or Is it a bug in Sonar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically and factually, it's not a bug: the rule finds that the code uses arbitrary numbers.

However, I find reasonable to think that this very particular use case, with fixed indices for column numbers, should be considered a false positive. And indeed, I see no point in trying to "fix" the code. So my suggestion is to either mark these individual issues as `False positive` or `Won't fix` in SonarQube, or to exclude this rule from analyzing your DAO classes.